# Breakpoint is not hit in VS2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I've a solution which is ported from VS (Visual Studio) 2010 to VS2017 from one machine to another. I could debug while I can't. I need to know what's the problem. When running, I see the breakpoint marks get changed to include a warning, but I can't find what can be wrong. It seems that everything is ok.

Comment: What is your warning messages? Which kind of app did you debug? As you said that you move your project from VS2010 to high VS2007, whether you could debug it normally in VS2010? If so, whether your project has certain assembly as the references which also need to be updated from VS2010 to VS2017?

Comment: the warning message that appears as tooltip when i hover the mouse on the hollowed breakpoint is: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document. The application brings up a login form. if the use is authenticated successfully, the main form will appear. but the problem is before the main form and in the first step, login form. yes, i could and still can debug it in VS2010 on the previous machine. about assemblies, since breakpoint is in my own source code, it seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: hey, i found that the debugging has this problem only when sources are located on a network drive. if i copy the whole solution to C: the problem will be resolved. with this knowledge, let's think again about it.

Comment: I suggest you report this issue to the Developer community site directly. Based on our discussion, it would have a limitation for network drive debugging. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b4497ab0-ff97-4237-ad3e-02f9a8e76bdb/vs2017-access-denied-when-attempting-to-run-under-the-debugger?forum=vsdebug

Comment: ok, thank you, i will

Comment: oh ic that the problem is described well there. so there's no need for me to add any more comments. i hope vs2017 get fixed soon.

Answer (score 3):

1)  Try to rebuild the application. Make sure that it's in the "**Debug**" mode.

2)  If it works fine in VS2010 but failed in VS2017, I wonder if Visual Studio gets confused the configuration of the correct code type, if so you may need manually selected the .NET version. If you are using Framework 3.5 in VS2010, but on Visual Studio 2017 you are using such as Framework 4.6, by default automatically determines the code types to debug (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0). In this case you need to click in "Select..." button on **"Attach to process" window and select Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0)**.

3)  Try to clear/delete all breakpoints from the Debug menu, choose Delete All Breakpoints. The reason is that it refreshes your Visual Studio setting file of your project.

4)  Potential **Workaround**: Uncheck "Require source files to match original versions ..." in Options, Debugging.

Comment: except for #2, i've tried all of them and they didn't resolve the problem. about #2, would you explain more? in VS2010, the program uses .net 4. i didn't change any settings. how can i know what version of .net is using and if required how can i change it? and do you mean i've to debug the code but attaching instead of pressing F5?

Comment: @hamidi if your project already targeted on .net framework 4.0, it might not be the .net version issue. May I ask if you've got any error after you built the project?  Since I just created a WinForm application in an old version VS on another machine and moved to my present machine(with VS2017), but it seems something's missing, Then the breakpoint is hollow but with an error"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The Source code is different from the original version". it turned some UI control was missing where i set the breakpoint, that's why the breakpoint would not be hit.

Comment: @hamidi If it's possible you could share a sample of your project with me, I will test it in my machine.

Comment: about the source code, i doubt it to be the source of the problem, because the application brings up a simple form. besides, the solution includes many sources that i can't put here because of the volume. about the error, i've set it not to continue running the project if an error has occurred (the famous dialog). besides, the error is different from what u get. i put it above. it seems that it can't find the PDB file or can't relate it to the source. i cleaned and rebuilt, but it didn't help. i've no clue how to fix it.

Comment: omg! i copied the whole solution from network drive into a local drive and the problem was resolved! why?
the drive is essentially provided by SFTP Net Drive which is mapped from a linux machine. maybe i've to change the settings of Windows/SFTP Net Drive? maybe the problem would happen even if the network drive would be a mapped drive from a Windows share?

Comment: @hamidi You might need use symbol server to find symbol files not on your local machine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_0 
Not sure what exactly cause the issue in your side, but this article lists some notes for where the debugger to search for .pdb file. 
As the solution you found could work, you could post it as an answer to let more people to notice it.

Comment: oh yeah! i think we may configure VS to use user temp folder (%temp%) as the folder to create intermediate codes in. i think this may resolve the problem. i've to wait until sunday to test it because it's in another site. but even in such a case, if the problem is resolved, still this is a question that why VS can't trust or read from a file it has created itself!!! it's more an MS issue than logical.

Comment: @hamidi, One issue is that whether you still use the same network drive in your VS2010, whether the breakpoint was hit in VS2010 using the same network drive?

Comment: no i don't. the network drive is used on with VS2017. in the other company which i use VS2010, i use virtualbox shared folder for mapping. still, it's a network drive in the view of Windows, but it's not a network drive which is provided by SFTP Net Drive. and in VS2010, i've not this problem. the other difference is that VS2010 is installed on Windows 7, while VS2017 is installed on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, changing from "**Release**" Mode to  the "**Debug**" mode works!

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the process, if the breakpoint icon turns hollow with the warning symbol, then the debugger cannot figure out what part of the program corresponds to that line of the source code.  This is typically because the build is out-of-date with the executable, DLL, or PDB file.

A common way to get into the this situation is to not notice that the build failed and then let the debugger try to run the old executable which doesn't correspond to the current sources.  It can also happen if Visual Studio gets confused about some of the dependencies and doesn't rebuild everything that needs to be rebuilt (which can happen after significant changes to the solution and/or project file(s), e.g., after an upgrade).

In these cases, clean out the build directory and force Visual Studio to rebuild everything.  This will usually get you back in sync.

When you set a breakpoint in DLL code, that breakpoint will appear in the hollow warning state until the DLL is loaded.  If your program uses delay-loading or if it manually loads the DLL (e.g., via a LoadLibrary call), you will commonly see this.  Once the DLL is loaded, any breakpoint icons in the DLL should return to the normal red-ball state.  If it doesn't yet you think the DLL should have been loaded.  Check the Output window in the debugger to see if it really was loaded and whether there were any warnings or errors about loading the corresponding symbols from that DLL.

Comment: thanks for your answer. before you answer, i had checked all of these. i don't LoadLibrary them. indeed i don't know how to do it in C#. the line belongs to a DLL which is loaded. otherwise, the form would not be shown. about the code not to be out-of-date, i see the change i've made, like the form to show the thrown exception. so the changed code is running. at the same code the breakpoint is hollow. i tried rebuilding and cleaning, but it didn't help too. i had done everything i though that it could help solving the problem with no success and now don't know what's still wrong.